# Is there a way in visio to show/hide a shape when clicking on another shape in Presentation Mode?

Tags: visio

I am trying to do a very basic user interface wireframe using Visio 2016.  I want to do things like show a dialog box when I click on a button and then hide that dialog box when I click on the "ok" in the dialog.  I've been previously doing this by completely copying the entire page and adding what I want to the new page and using the "Hyperlink" option.  It would be a lot easier if there were a way to show or hide a shape when I click on another shape.  Is there any capability like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Presentation Mode? No. There is almost no interaction available in Presentation Mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some code to run in fullscreen mode. I've hooked the application MouseMove event in the sample below. It makes the outline of the shape you are over fatter while the mouse is over that shape.

You can test the code by drawing a bunch of rectangles on a page, then moving the mouse in fullscreen mode.

I wasn't able to trap MouseDown in fullscreen mode, though.

More notes in the code's comments!

```vb
Option Explicit

'// Notes:
'//
'// - This code works in full screen mode!
'// - The mouse-up code doesn't work if you drag the shape,
'//   (which won't be an issue in full-screen mode!)

Dim WithEvents m_visApp As Visio.Application

Private m_visShpMouseDown As Visio.Shape
Private m_lineWeightFormulaU As String

Private Sub Document_RunModeEntered(ByVal doc As IVDocument)

  '// Toggle RunMode on and off via the blue triangle button just
  '// right of the Stop/Reset button. This lets you reset the
  '// code without closing and opening the file every time! Also,
  '// this proc runs when you open the file, so m_visApp will
  '// be set up to receive events!

  Set m_visApp = Visio.Application

End Sub

Private Sub m_visApp_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal KeyButtonState As Long, ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double, CancelDefault As Boolean)


  Dim pg As Visio.Page
  Set pg = m_visApp.ActivePage
  If (pg Is Nothing) Then GoTo Cleanup

  Dim shp As Visio.Shape
  For Each shp In pg.Shapes

    If (shp.HitTest(x, y, 0)) Then

      '// The mouse is over a shape.

      If (shp Is m_visShpMouseDown) Then
        Debug.Print "MouseMove over same shape! " & DateTime.Now
        GoTo Cleanup
      Else

        Debug.Print "MouseMove over shape! " & DateTime.Now

        '// Restore any previously mouse-overed shape:
        Call m_restoreShape

        '// Save the original lineweight and change it to
        '// something thicker:
        m_lineWeightFormulaU = shp.CellsU("LineWeight").FormulaU
        Set m_visShpMouseDown = shp

        '// Make the lineweight thick:
        shp.CellsU("LineWeight").FormulaForceU = "5pt"

        GoTo Cleanup

        '// Note: the above won't change the lineweights
        '// for all shapes in a group. If you intend to use
        '// this on grouped shapes, you'll have to recurse
        '// into the group, which makes things a bit more
        '// complicated!


      End If

    End If

  Next shp


  Call m_restoreShape

Cleanup:
  Set shp = Nothing
  Set pg = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub m_restoreShape()

  If (m_visShpMouseDown Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

  '// Restore the shape's original lineweight:
  m_visShpMouseDown.CellsU("LineWeight").FormulaU = m_lineWeightFormulaU

  '// Clear the mouse-down variables:
  Set m_visShpMouseDown = Nothing
  m_lineWeightFormulaU = vbNullString

End Sub
```